# Not able to read multiple struct type messages from C pipe

Tags: c, multithreading, pipe, ipc

I'm trying to develop a program that will initiate 2 child processes to run and these child processes will read all the files in one directory and pass the information to another child to create those files in another directory.
Below is my code for the same. But I'm not able to read messages from the pipe. If I pass a hardcoded string object, I'm able to read that from the pipe. But not the struct object I'm trying to pass.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>  //Header file for sleep(). man 3 sleep for details.
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 1024

// Struct to store the file name and content
struct FileDetails{
    char *file_name;
    char *file_content;
};


// Helper function to create file at a given path and with given content.
void * createFile(struct FileDetails fileDetail){
int status;
   FILE *fptr;

   fptr = fopen(fileDetail.file_name,"a");

   if(fptr == NULL)
   {

      perror("Error!");   
      return NULL;          
   }

   fprintf(fptr,"%s",fileDetail.file_content);
   fclose(fptr);
   return NULL;
}

//Helper function used to copy two strings into one and return new string
char* strAppend(char* str1, char* str2){
        char * new_str ;
        if((new_str = malloc(strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)+1)) != NULL){
            new_str[0] = '\0';   // ensures the memory is an empty string
            strcat(new_str,str1);
            strcat(new_str,str2);
        } else {
            printf("%s","malloc failed!\n");
            // exit?
        }
    return new_str;
}


// Each child will execute this helper funtion. It takes one argument which is the location of the directory to read all files from and send data to other child.
// Second argument is the pipe where we write
void *threadUtility(void *vargp, int* fd1)
{
    // Store directory pointer
    DIR* directoryPtr;
    // Store file pointer
    FILE *entry_file;
    struct dirent *current_file;
    int i;

    char* directory = (char *)vargp;
    printf("Process started for directory: %s\n", directory);
    directoryPtr = opendir(directory);

    if(directoryPtr==NULL) {
        printf("Error! Unable to read directory: %s\n", directory);
        exit(1);
    }

    close(fd1[0]);  // Close reading end of first pipe

    while((current_file=readdir(directoryPtr)) != NULL) {
        if (!strcmp (current_file->d_name, "."))
            continue;
        if (!strcmp (current_file->d_name, ".."))
            continue;
        struct FileDetails fileDetail;
        fileDetail.file_name = malloc(strlen(current_file->d_name) + 1);

        fileDetail.file_name = current_file->d_name;

        // Appending directory path to file name to read contents
        char * new_str = strAppend(directory, current_file->d_name);
        //printf("FileName FQN: %s\n", fileDetail.file_name);

        entry_file = fopen(new_str, "r");
        struct stat sb;
        stat(new_str, &sb);

        char *file_contents = malloc(sb.st_size);
        fileDetail.file_content = malloc(sb.st_size);
        if (entry_file != NULL) {
            //Looping through each line of file to read all lines.
            while (fscanf(entry_file, "%[^\n] ", file_contents) != EOF) {
                fileDetail.file_content = strAppend(fileDetail.file_content, file_contents) ;
                fileDetail.file_content = strAppend(fileDetail.file_content, "/n") ;
            }
        } else{
            perror("Failed: ");
            exit(1);
        }
    fclose(entry_file);
    //printf("Writing to pipe: %s\n", fileDetail.file_name);

    if (write(fd1[1], &fileDetail, sizeof(struct FileDetails)) < 0) {
                printf("error writing");
    }
    }

    close(fd1[1]);
    closedir(directoryPtr);
    printf("Process ended for directory: %s\n", directory);
    return NULL;
}

// This program takes two command line argument which are direectory paths of two location.   
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    // If 2 paths not provided the program will terminate
    if( argc != 3 ) {
      printf("Provide two directory paths:  %i\n", argc);
      exit(1);
   }
    
    //Pipes for communication
    int fd1[2];  // Used to store two ends of first pipe
    int fd2[2];  // Used to store two ends of second pipe
    //Create pipes
    if (pipe(fd1)==-1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Pipe Failed" );
        return 1;
    }
    if (pipe(fd2)==-1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Pipe Failed" );
        return 1;
    }

   // Process ids for two child processes
    pid_t dir_one_child_process, dir_two_child_process;
    dir_one_child_process = fork();
    if (dir_one_child_process == 0) {
        /* Child One Process */
        threadUtility(strAppend(argv[1],"/"), fd1);
        wait(NULL);            
        // Reading messages sent by 2nd child
        close(fd2[1]); // Close writing end of second pip  
        // Read string from child, print it and close
        // reading end.
        struct FileDetails readForSecond;
        int n_bytes;
            while (read(fd2[0], &readForSecond, sizeof(&readForSecond)) > 0) {
                printf("From Child One: %s\n", readForSecond.file_name);
                // Here you have to call the createFile function in order to create the file once you get the FileDetail object
                //I'm stuck here
                //sleep(1);
                }
        printf("From Child Two: %s\n", readForSecond.file_name);
        close(fd2[0]);
    } else {
        dir_two_child_process = fork();

        if (dir_two_child_process == 0) {
            /* Child Two Process */

            close(fd1[1]);  // Close writing end of first pipe
            struct FileDetails readForFirst;
            int n_bytes;
            while (read(fd1[0], &readForFirst, sizeof(&readForFirst)) > 0) {
                printf("From Child One file_name: %s\n", readForFirst.file_name);
                // Here you have to call the createFile function in order to create the file once you get the FileDetail object
                //I'm stuck here
                //sleep(1);
                }
                                printf("reading ends:");

            // Close both reading ends
            close(fd1[0]);
            threadUtility(strAppend(argv[2],"/"), fd2);
        } else {
                /* Parent Code waiting for two childs to end*/
                waitpid(dir_one_child_process, NULL, 0);
                waitpid(dir_two_child_process, NULL, 0);            
            printf("Main Function Ends. Exiting\n");
        }
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need multiple processes for that?

Comment: The purpose of the program seems to be: "copy files to another directory". But why do you what such a complex solution for something that are pretty simple to do?

Comment: The idea here is not to copy the directories. It is more of learning C and IPC using pipes.

Answer (score 0):

Here it one bug:

```
write(fd1[1], &fileDetail, sizeof(struct FileDetails))
```

`sizeof(struct FileDetails)` is **not** the size of the data that you have stored using the pointers in `fileDetail`. Since `struct FileDetails` is

```
struct FileDetails{
    char *file_name;
    char *file_content;
};
```

it's simply the size of two pointers (which is typically 2x4 or 2x8).

You can check the size using:

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(struct FileDetails));
```

So it looks as-if you sending two pointer values instead of the content of the files. That's not what you want.

Further, this is wrong:

```
read(fd2[0], &readForSecond, sizeof(&readForSecond))
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                             This is size-of a single pointer
```

Comment: I'm sure there are bugs in the code, hence not working. Could you also provide the changes to the things you have pointed above?